# Meteor on Heroku With MongoHQ Mongodb doesn't read data

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, meteor, mongohq

I've taken the example Leaderboard meteor app (http://meteor.com/examples/leaderboard) and used Demeteorizer to convert it to a simple Node.JS app (https://github.com/onmodulus/demeteorizer).

I'm trying to use an external mongohq for my database, and I followed the instructions at http://ondrej-kvasnovsky.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-deploy-meteor-on-heroku-with.html to connect the two and then deployed it.

The issue I'm facing is that the code is able to connect to the database and populate it with values (as I can see the new collection in MongoHQ along with the data in it), but when I go to the herokuapp, it doesn't read the data. So it seems that the isServer content works, but the isClient isn't able to pick up the data from the db.

The live site is at: http://qawsedrf.herokuapp.com/

Any idea why this is happening??

Help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome Dev tools console I get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`

Don't know where or what that comes from but it should be a start for you to find the error.

If you want an easy way to deploy to Heroku check out this buildpack: https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite

(There might be a bug in that one right now though, here's a fork that should work if the original don't work: https://github.com/nate-strauser/heroku-buildpack-meteorite)

Comment: Yeah, I've successfully used the buildpack in the past, but that I am using a buildpack for my deploy, but all meteor buildpacks I've come across work only with the Mongo instance provided from within Heroku as mentioned here: https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor/blob/master/bin/release#L8 ... but I'm trying to use an external mongohq instance, so it doesn't work. Even the meteorite buildpack you linked too needs the mongoq:sandbox addon, but as much as possible, I'm trying to use an external mongohq instance

Comment: Ah ok, sorry – I can see now I did not read your question properly. But what about the "process" variable, any clue?